# paypal sandbox setup seller account buy now

Tags: paypal, sandbox

Ok, so I have created my buyer and seller accounts in the sandbox, i select the seller account and press the yellow button at the bottom 'Enter sandbox test site' - a new window opens and says im logged in, i want to go to the merchant services to create a buy now button to test my site, but when i press on the 'Business' tab at the top, it says page not found.

(i have tried logging out and then logging in with the new email, the one with numbers in it which they make, and their password they give you but id doesnt recognise it)

is this a bug or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Go to 'Profile' > My selling tools > Manage my buttons > Update, instead.